# How to install Azure ADF SelfHosted IR ON VM in quiet mode command line

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-adf

I am using Azure and in Azure i created an Azure Data Factory

Then i am try to install Self Hosted IR on my VM
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717

Documentation does not tell what parameters i need to pass to this msi when run on command line in quiet unattended mode..

Key is absolutely required but what is the name of that parameter in msi?

What other parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-automation-scripts) provides a script for automating the install of the SHIR software. Basically you first install the software then you register it using the key.